# Partition key as variable in python azure storage table

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-table-storage

I have partition key in azure storage table as below, partition key is string here.
for each day, the partition key is Date in string format. if i take count of records based on partiotion key (03042018) and rowkey as (1) . i get 2 counts.
partitionkey      rowkey      timestamp                           desc
02042018              1           2018-11-26T01:23:57.149Z         'abc'
02042018              1           2018-11-26T23:46:57.149Z          'def'
03042018              1           2018-11-27T01:46:57.149Z         'fff'
03042018              1           2018-11-27T01:47:57.149Z          'ggg'
03042018              2           2018-11-27T01:48:01.149Z          'ggg'

How to pass the partition key as variable in the below query. 
Here, partitionkey is 'taskseattle', but i want to pass 02042014 on today and when run the python script it should pass 03042018 in the below query in the partitionkey.

a='02042018' (how to pass a in below partition key)
tasks = table_service.query_entities('tasktable', "PartitionKey eq 'tasksSeattle'")

Comment: Just to clarify, you just want to pass the variable a='02042018' instead of the 'tasksSeattle'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to pass a variable to the query, please use the code below:

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService
from azure.cosmosdb.table.models import Entity

table_service = TableService(account_name='your_account',account_key='your_key')

a='03042018'
tasks = table_service.query_entities('tasktable',filter='PartitionKey eq \'' + a + '\'')
for task in tasks:
    print(task.description)
```

The test result as below:
[image]

Comment: in the similar case, can i add rowkey and pull records based on multiple row keys (more than 1) ? for the same partition key

Comment: Do you mean something like `filter="PartitionKey eq '0304' and (rowkey=1 or rowkey =2)"` ? Note that the above code may not work, I just use it to explain what you want:)